# What is the etiquette for leaving after a stay with an unexpected host?

Tags: united-states, etiquette

Say you go with a few friends on a night out, downtown fairly far from where you live. Afterwards, rather than dealing with how to get home, a friend of a friend offers the couch in their shared apartment. Not ideal, but you take it for convenience.

In this case, you wake up at 7am and assume your unexpected host is still sleeping. What's the proper etiquette for leaving? Is it standard to leave an appreciation note before you leave, or wait until the host wakes up?

Comment: Could you also add how well you know this host and if you made arrangements prior to sleeping over?

Comment: I disagree about this question being primarily opinion based. It's a pretty obvious thing to ask about, because what matters most is the host's opinion.

Comment: @Anilla a casual acquaintance, friend of a close friend, and no prior arrangements

Answer (score 7):

You could do either - there is no single answer to this. Some people would like a morning chat over coffee, others would like there to be no trace in the morning, others may want to cook a big breakfast.

It's really down to you. Do you feel comfortable having a conversation with a stranger, however brief, which is basically a thank you for letting me crash?

What I would probably try and do is quietly tidy up anything I may have messed up, wash up any glasses, leave a note and head off.